# How to get firebase token if onNewToken not called, because the token already created?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

As we know we can get `firebase token` on `onNewToken(...)` in our class inherited of `FirebaseMessagingService`. But I have a question, that method will not call on update app case, and if I already have a token before, but I didn't save it. How to get it??

Example: In my class inherit from `FirebaseMessagingService`

```kotlin
class CustomFirebaseService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

override fun onNewToken(newToken: String) {
    supper.onNewToken(newToken)
    // I have token in here, but I already didn't save it on any where (sharedperf, db,..)
}
```

And now in my application, I need to use it, but I don't sure what the best way to get it??

```kotlin
class App: Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        // I need to use token here, but method onNewToken will not called, because the current token is valid.
    }

}
```

Maybe, Can I use `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(..)`? Do it duplicate with my custom service??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Firebase documentation on [getting the current registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#retrieve-the-current-registration-token) says:

> ```
> FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
>     .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
>         @Override
>         public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
>             if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
>                 Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
>                 return;
>             }
>
>            // Get new Instance ID token
>             String token = task.getResult().getToken();
>
>            // Log and toast
>             String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
>             Log.d(TAG, msg);
>             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>         }
>     });
> ```

You typically only need this in development, as the initial token is typically generated before you have an `onNewToken`. Once your app is in production, the `onNewToken` code will be called from the moment the first token is generated.